# Merge 20+ xml files with 7000+nodes into one using java

Tags: java, xml, merge

im trying to merge more than 20 xml files into one, any of them contains more than 7000 nodes
code that im using for that is like this

```
private void createFile(String month, String year) throws Exception {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("Config.properties"));
    String edb = prop.getProperty("EDB");
    String bbbCode = prop.getProperty("BBB");
    String InFolder = prop.getProperty("IN");
    String OutFolder = prop.getProperty("OUT");
    String Particija = prop.getProperty("DISK");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    String ImeFile = "O3" + dateFormat.format(date) + "0000001.UJP." + bbbCode + ".xml";
    String MesecGodina = month + "/" + year;
    DateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date dateTime = new Date();
    String DatPratka = dateTimeFormat.format(dateTime);
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("UplatiIsplatiMesecIzvestaj");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);
        // PrireduvacVodecki elements
        Element PrireduvacVodecki = doc.createElement("PrireduvacVodecki");
        rootElement.appendChild(PrireduvacVodecki);
        // edbElement elements
        Element edbElement = doc.createElement("O3_Edb");
        edbElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(edb));
        PrireduvacVodecki.appendChild(edbElement);
        // imeFileElement elements
        Element imeFileElement = doc.createElement("O3_ImeFile");
        imeFileElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ImeFile));
        PrireduvacVodecki.appendChild(imeFileElement);
        // mesecGodinaElement elements
        Element mesecGodinaElement = doc.createElement("O3_MesecGodina");
        mesecGodinaElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(MesecGodina));
        PrireduvacVodecki.appendChild(mesecGodinaElement);
        // datPratkaElement elements
        Element datPratkaElement = doc.createElement("O3_DatPratka");
        datPratkaElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(DatPratka));
        PrireduvacVodecki.appendChild(datPratkaElement);
        // rbrPratkaElement elements
        Element rbrPratkaElement = doc.createElement("O3_RbrPratka");
        rbrPratkaElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("0000001"));
        PrireduvacVodecki.appendChild(rbrPratkaElement);

        File dir = new File(Particija + ":\\" + InFolder + "\\");
        File[] rootFiles = dir.listFiles();
        int stavki = 0;
        for (File rootFile : rootFiles) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + rootFile + "\n");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(rootFile);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document docc = db.parse(new InputSource(in));
            docc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            int y = docc.getElementsByTagName("UplataIsplata").getLength();
            display.setText(display.getText() + Integer.toString(y) + "\n");
            stavki = stavki + y;
            for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                // UplataIsplata elements
                Element UplataIsplata = doc.createElement("UplataIsplata");
                rootElement.appendChild(UplataIsplata);

                Element idElement = doc.createElement("O3_Id");
                idElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Id").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(idElement);

                Element sifraUplMestoElement = doc.createElement("O3_Sifra_uplmesto");
                sifraUplMestoElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Sifra_uplmesto").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(sifraUplMestoElement);

                Element sifraKompElement = doc.createElement("O3_Sifra_komp");
                sifraKompElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Sifra_komp").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(sifraKompElement);

                Element serNumTicketElement = doc.createElement("O3_Serial_num_ticket");
                serNumTicketElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Serial_num_ticket").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(serNumTicketElement);

                Element codeTicketElement = doc.createElement("O3_Code_ticket");
                codeTicketElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Code_ticket").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(codeTicketElement);

                Element vremeUplataElement = doc.createElement("O3_Vreme_uplata");
                vremeUplataElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Vreme_uplata").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(vremeUplataElement);

                Element iznosUplataElement = doc.createElement("O3_Iznos_uplata");
                iznosUplataElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Iznos_uplata").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(iznosUplataElement);

                Element iznosMoznaDobivkaElement = doc.createElement("O3_Iznos_mozna_dobivka");
                iznosMoznaDobivkaElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Iznos_mozna_dobivka").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(iznosMoznaDobivkaElement);

                Element iznosIsplatenElement = doc.createElement("O3_Iznos_isplaten");
                iznosIsplatenElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Iznos_isplaten").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(iznosIsplatenElement);

                Element brojKombinaciiElement = doc.createElement("O3_Broj_kombinacii");
                brojKombinaciiElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Broj_kombinacii").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(brojKombinaciiElement);

                Element vkupenKoefElement = doc.createElement("O3_Vkupen_koef");
                vkupenKoefElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Vkupen_koef").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(vkupenKoefElement);

                Element vidTransakcijaElement = doc.createElement("O3_Vid_transakcija");
                vidTransakcijaElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Vid_transakcija").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(vidTransakcijaElement);

                Element statusTicketElement = doc.createElement("O3_Status_ticket");
                statusTicketElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(docc.getElementsByTagName("O2_Status_ticket").item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
                UplataIsplata.appendChild(statusTicketElement);

            }
        }

        // vkBrStavkiElement elements
        Element vkBrStavkiElement = doc.createElement("O3_VkBrStavki");
        vkBrStavkiElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(stavki)));
        PrireduvacVodecki.appendChild(vkBrStavkiElement);
        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(Particija + ":\\" + OutFolder + "\\" + ImeFile));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "WINDOWS-1251");
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "File Saved!", "XML Merge Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);
        mainPanel.setCursor(java.awt.Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but after some time of creating file program stops working.
how to change this code to write to file part by part not from memory

Comment: What do mean "stops working"? It stalls? It throws an exception? It exits without any exception but the file corrupt? ...

Comment: i try with 2 input files on development pc, and create output file without any problem, i put program on production pc with 30 files in input and after all night the program stops i'm trying now again on development pc with 30 files in input and i will write any exception that will throws

Comment: i got this exception                                              Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Oh, so you are doing this on the EDT. You should spawn a thread for this. But even that will not solve the problem...

Comment: and ... what i need to do ?